# ExPex: Continuing labels of subparts in multipart examples

Tags: linguistics, expex

I rely heavily on ExPex and have a problem in automatically labeling subparts of multipart examples:

```
Consider the following construction:

\pex<like>
\a[label=0] I like X
\xe

Some folks might say something like:

\pex[exno=\getref{like}]
\a I like food
\a I like pens
\xe

Observe the similarity to the construction:

\pex<wantz>
\a[label=0] Me wantz X
\a Me wantz food
\a Me wantz pens
\xe

But there’s more!

\pex[exno=\getref{like}]
\a I like LaTeX
\a I like ExPex
\xe
```

I get the result on the left side but want the result on the right side:

[image]

In other words, I want the numbers of the subparts of a given multipart examples to just go on. I could do it using \a[label=] every time and keeping track by myself, but that seems tedious and unreliable.

I suspect that there is some way I could use \pexcnt to do the trick, but even after reading the manual a few times, I have not clue how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These ideas comes to my mind:

- Create a *command* `\saveseries{<name>}` where `<name>` defines a *macro* (and therefore its syntax should be of a macro, i.e only letters) to save the current `\pexcnt` for later use. This *command* should be put at end of the `\pex` structure (before of `\xe`).
- Create a *command* `\resumeseries{<name>}` for continuing labels in other `\pex`. This command must be put at begin of the other `\pex` structure (where you wish continuing the labeling), and don't forget to put the `nopreamble` option for avoiding a change of line.

### Warnings

- You must put again `\saveseries{...}` if you want to break the labeling in other block.
- You must use a `<name>` in `\resumeseries` already defined with `\saveseries` to avoid an error like

> ```
> `! Undefined control sequence.`
>
> `<recently read> \<name>`
> ```

### The full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcommand{\saveseries}[1]{\expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{\noexpand\pexcnt\the\pexcnt\relax}}
\newcommand{\resumeseries}[1]{\expandafter\csname#1\endcsname\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
Consider the following construction:

\pex<like>
\a[label=0] I like X
\xe

Some folks might say something like:

\pex[exno=\getref{like}]
\a I like food
\a I like pens
\a I don't know
\saveseries{myserie}
\xe

Observe the similarity to the construction: 

\pex<wantz>
\a[label=0] Me wantz X
\a Me wantz food
\a Me wantz pens
\xe

But there’s more!

\pex[exno=\getref{like},nopreamble]  \resumeseries{myserie} 
\a I like LaTeX
\a I like ExPex
\xe
\end{document}
```

This is not sufficiently tested but I think the desired result is obtained.

[image]

Comment: Neat idea! Thanks a lot, it works better than expected!